# What mean flag -gd for npm intsall command?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Could not find what mean flag "-gd" for npm install command.

It works, for example:
[Sublime Text less2css package](https://github.com/timdouglas/sublime-less2css)

Comment: -g stands for global. It installs a package in user directory to be accessible in system globally. For -d not sure. Suppose that stands for installing also additional packages useful for development (like unit test frameworks etc..)